# Add files to Dock on macOS using the command line

Tags: macos, file, command-line, terminal, dock

How can I add a file to the Dock in macOS using the Terminal?

Typically this is done using Finder, by dragging and dropping the file icon into the Dock. I am looking for a programmatic way using the command line / Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dockutil`](https://github.com/kcrawford/dockutil/releases/tag/3.0.2) works flawlessly. Download the `.pkg` from their [github Releases page](https://github.com/kcrawford/dockutil/releases).

Comment: This program is dead now. It doesn't work with python3.

Comment: Confirmed. `❯ dockutil --help
zsh: /opt/homebrew/bin/dockutil: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/python: no such file or directory`

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist ok apparently they have a swift version now, updated with those instructions instead

Comment: just use their already built .dmg: https://github.com/kcrawford/dockutil/releases

Answer (score 4):

To add file `/path/to/file name.pdf` to the right end of the Dock use the following while replacing `file:///path/to/file%20name.pdf` with the correct fully qualified pathname:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add "<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>file:///path/to/file%20name.pdf</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>15</integer></dict><key>file-type</key><integer>32</integer></dict><key>tile-type</key><string>file-tile</string></dict>"; killall Dock
```

This answer is courtesy of *[user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894)*, and was deeply buried in the comments of a related question about adding **apps** to the Dock: [How to create Dock entries via Terminal in macOS Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/255652/329079)